Using Mantel's Theorem To Solve A Classic Ramsey Theory Type Qestion
The problem: "Given any set of 6 people, show that there are (at least) 3 mutual acquaintances or 3 mutual strangers".
This is equivalent to proving that for every pair of graphs $G$ and $\overline{G}$ on 6 vertices, there exists a 3-clique in at least one of them. Or proving that a triangle-free graph $G$ on 6 vertices must have an independent set of size at least 3.
Of course one could just use Ramsey's theorem, but my non-Ramsey proof seemed fairly standard, considering the neighbors and non-neighbors of some vertex in the graph. But that got me thinking about the similarities to a common proof for Mantel's Theorem by extremality, and I now wonder whether the theorem can be used to proof the claim.
My question: I want to try to solve this using Mantel's Theorem and some combinatorics only.
My attempt: I don't know where to go after noting that Mantel's theorem tells us that $|E(G)| \leq \lfloor{6^2/4}\rfloor = 9$ and $|E(\overline{G})| \geq 6$. Further, we know the possible pairs of sizes of edge sets (9 and 6, 7 and 8). This, along with the fact that triangle-free is such a strong assumption leads me to believe there is some way to resolve this, possibly with combinatorics along the line of reasoning that for each of the ${6 \choose 3} = 20$ triples, there should be at least 1 edge between them, somehow not counting overlaps.

@user14111 I am assuming $G$ is the triangle-free graph and thus $|E(G)| \leq 9$, which implies that $|E(\overline{G})| \leq 6$. The complement of $G$ is under no triangle free restriction, this is simply from the fact that $|E(G)| + |E(\overline{G})| = {6 \choose 2}$.
I assume you meant to say "maximum number of edges" and I agree. It should follow that the number of edges in $\overline{G}$ is at most 6.

Sorry, you're correct, I had an extended brain fart! It's totally $|E(\overline{G})| \geq 6$. We agree on everything else, but I'm still not how to proceed even when we know $G$ has exactly 8 edges.

You just have to prove that, if $G$ is a triangle-free graph with $6$ vertices and $7$ edges, then $\overline G$ contains a triangle. It seems to me that there are only $4$ nonisomorphic triangle-free graphs with $6$ vertices and $7$ edges. To start with, such a graph must contain a $C_4$.. Now how many ways can you add $2$ vertices and $3$ edges without forming a triangle?

Sorry for giving you the wrong idea and I appreciate the help, but I am looking for something that follows from Mantel's theorem and a general counting argument instead of the graph theory case work for when $G$ has exactly 8 edges. It may be too tight or unreasonable of a question to ask but this is what I was primarily interested in, not necessarily in actually proving the result as there are many ways to do this.

Good luck with that. Now, if you just wanted a counting argument, you could use Goodman's theorem which says that, if each edge of $K_n$ is colored red or blue, there are at least $M(n)=\binom n3-\left\lfloor\frac n2\left\lfloor\left(\frac{n-1}2\right)^2\right\rfloor\right\rfloor;$ monochromatic triangles; in particular, if $n=6$, there are at least $M(6)=2$ of them. But that doesn't involve Mantel's theorem.
